# How to change the parent node of inserted html

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that inputs a html file too the website a specified but i want too change who the parent is

HTML Injector

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);
        div.parentElement = document.getElementsByClassName("fullheight").item;
    } else {
        console.log('files not found');
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL("/Test.html"), true);
xhttp.send();
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <title>Embedded Hello World</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <link href="HelloWorld.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="HelloWorld.js"></script>
</head><body>
<p class="test">Hello World!</p>
</body></html>
```

CSS

```
.test
{
 color:white;
}
body
{
 background-color: rgb(20,20,20,1) !important;
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5Ntv.png)
I want the Hello World! bar too be under the tool bar

[Orange is The Bar and Purple is The toolbar i want it under](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj1WY.png)
Any help would be appreciated Thank You!

Comment: Just select the element you want it after and insert if after? Does the purple element have dynamically changing id/classes/position? Or what keeps you from doing that?

Comment: @GergelySzabo But how would i do that? Im new too extensions

Comment: Instead of `document.body` use `document.querySelector(".fullheight")` and remove the entire line with div.parentElement

Comment: @wOxxOm didnt work :/

Comment: It means there's no such element at the time your code runs.